# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.0.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0

Tags: asp.net-core

So I wanted to build a ASP.NET Core web application with the React-Redux template. But seems like I can't even use the default template (can't build it). Because I keep on getting errors like the one in the title. Furthermore Microsoft.NETCore.App is blocked by the project. Has anyone found a workaround or a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've managed to solve the issue. Instead of installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.All version 2.0.5, install the version 2.0.3 and it will be fine.

Comment: do you really mean `2.0.5`? Cause title says about error with `2.0.2` version